# PHP multiple foreach loops

Tags: php, foreach

I've got two sections of a for each loop in PHP. One loops through each of the image files in a directory and produces their name as a title based on the heading of the image.

Now I need a second `foreach` loop to iterate through an array I have and assign a link to the `<a>` tag wrapped around the generated heading.

So here's my script:

```
$a = array();
$unis = array("http://www.aber.ac.uk/en/", "http://www.bangor.ac.uk/", "http://www.cardiff.ac.uk/");
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "databasename");

$dir = '../assets/img/universities';
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if (preg_match("/\.png$/", $file)) $a[] = $file;
        elseif (preg_match("/\.jpg$/", $file)) $a[] = $file;
        elseif (preg_match("/\.jpeg$/", $file)) $a[] = $file;
    }
    closedir($handle);
}

foreach ($a as $i) {
    echo "<div class='col-sm-4'>
            <div class='grid-box'>
                <img class='uni-image' src='" . $dir . '/' . $i . "' />
            ";

    foreach($unis as $j) {
            echo "<a href='$j'><h5>" . pathinfo($i, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . "</h5></a>";
    }
    //END OF GRID-BOX
    echo "</div></div>"; //END OF COLUMN 
}
```

But at the moment what is happening is the last link `http://cardiff.ac.uk` is assigned as the link to **all** the heading tags. Could someone tell me where my logic is off?

Comment: By looking at those loops - for each of your file names, you are going to have a full list of anchors based on $unis. Is this intended? Or do you only want to output the anchors list once?

Comment: maybe start with some better variable names. $a, $i, $j, ... not really helping. Indentation could help aswel

Comment: @DaveO'Dwyer I want one link to be assigned to each heading. Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you supply actual output vs desired output? It's hard to imagine what you're looking for and a quick test on my system doesn't show a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using `DirectoryIterator` you can do it in single loop

```
$dirIter = new DirectoryIterator('/folder');
$links = ["http://www.aber.ac.uk/en/", "http://www.bangor.ac.uk/", "http://www.cardiff.ac.uk/"];
foreach ($dir as $dirIter){

    if ($dir->isDot()) continue;
    if ($dir->isDir()) continue;
    if (!preg_match('/\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg)$/', $dir->getFilname())) continue;

    foreach($links as $link) {
        echo "<div class='col-sm-4'><div class='grid-box'>
              <img class='uni-image' src='", $dir->getFilename(), "' />";
        echo "<a href='", $link, "'><h5>", $dir->getFilename(), "</h5></a>";
        echo "</div></div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the issue of assigning the appropriate link to the generated heading.